# Display Access query in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database and have some built in queries in the database. The same data is stored in geodatabase with the spatial information. Now I want to follow this process:

```
Access-> push out query-> open ArcMap mxd -> display results.
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am using MS access 2010 and ArcGIS 10.1. Any help on this is most welcome.

Comment: Can you use a real RDBMS like Postgresql or at least SQLite?

Comment: Hello Everyone thanks a lot for the comments, The database is SQL backend and Access front end independent non spatial database. The database does have the x and y /lat/lon columns. The queries built inside the database need to be used in ArcMAP to display results and add a new layer, should I use VBA? or python for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think a less intrusive method is to convert your queries into make table queries which could write the output back into the Access database or maybe another. Your MXD could then connect to these tables using [OLE](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32976).

If you needed to do some extra processing may be wrap them up in a macro?

If you wrap up your processing steps in a macro then the macro can be called from within ArcMap using VBA and automation. It's worth mentioning that ESRI are on a mission to drop VBA in favour of Python and I've never attempted to automate Access from Python.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Access, but I'll echo blah238, if you can use any other real RDBMS, then do so...

If not:

- First be sure that you are starting with an actual
  Personal Geodatabase (i.e. one that was created in ArcGIS/Catalog).
- Create your query. Be sure to include both OBJECTID and Shape in addition to any other fields you need. Also, only include a single Shape field.
- **(Optional)** Select the query into a table (You can just use the query directly if you want)
- Open the GDB_GeoColumns table.
- Add a new row for your table/query. Set the TableName to the name of your query/table. The rest of the fields (shape type, extent, etc.) can be copied from whatever data source you queried from.
- Open the PGDB in ArcGIS, the table/query should now be visible as a feature class within the PGDB.

*This is the bare minimum to get a query to show up as a feature class in ArcGIS. They may be some weird behavior and I definitely wouldn't try doing any sort of edit operations on it from ArcGIS*